# Kryo throwing " Encountered unregistered class ID: 44"

Tags: java, serialization, kryo

Kyro is throwing me the following message:

```
  com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Encountered unregistered class ID: 44
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:137)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClass(Kryo.java:693)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:804)
        at main.java.com.bag.client.TestClient.processReadReturn(TestClient.java:246)
        at main.java.com.bag.client.TestClient.replyReceived(TestClient.java:221)
        at bftsmart.communication.client.netty.NettyClientServerCommunicationSystemClientSide.channelRead0(NettyClientServerCommunicationSystemClientSide.java:244)
        at bftsmart.communication.client.netty.NettyClientServerCommunicationSystemClientSide.channelRead0(NettyClientServerCommunicationSystemClientSide.java:65)
        at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:292)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:278)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:277)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:264)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:292)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:278)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:962)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:485)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:399)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:371)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I serialize with the following snippet:

```
KryoPool pool = new KryoPool.Builder(factory).softReferences().build();
Kryo kryo = pool.borrow();
Input input = new Input(bytes);
ArrayList<NodeStorage> nodeStorage = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<RelationshipStorage> relationshipStorage = new ArrayList<>();
kryo.writeClassAndObject(output, nodeStorage);
kryo.writeClassAndObject(output, relationshipStorage);
```

The factory:

```
 private KryoFactory factory = () ->
{
    Kryo kryo = new Kryo();
    kryo.register(NodeStorage.class, 100);
    kryo.register(RelationshipStorage.class, 200);
    // configure kryo instance, customize settings
    return kryo;
};
```

Deserialization with the following:

```
KryoPool pool = new KryoPool.Builder(factory).softReferences().build();
Kryo kryo = pool.borrow();
ArrayList<NodeStorage>         nodeResult         = (ArrayList<NodeStorage>) kryo.readClassAndObject(input);
ArrayList<RelationshipStorage> relationshipResult = (ArrayList<RelationshipStorage>) kryo.readClassAndObject(input);
```

The crash log appears the moment it executes the first arrayList deserialization.

NodeStorage and Relationship storage contain Various Strings, int and maps with more strings.

The full code can be found here:

https://github.com/Raycoms/thesis

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a new serializer.

```
public class ArraySerializer extends CollectionSerializer{

   protected Collection create (Kryo kryo, Input input, Class<Collection> type) {
        return new ArrayList();
   }
}

kryo.register(Arrays.asList().getClass(), new ArraySerializer());
```